# bash: pgrep in a commad substition

Tags: bash, grep, command-substitution

I want to build a small script (called `check_process.sh`) that checks if a certain process `$PROC_NAME` is running. If it does, it returns its PID or -1 otherwise.

My idea is to use `pgrep -f <STRING>` in a command substitution.

If I run this code directly in the command line:

```
export ARG1=foo_name
export RES=$(pgrep -f ${ARG1})
if [[ $RES == "" ]]; then echo "-1" ; else echo "$RES"; fi
```

everything goes fine: `PID` or -1 depending on the process status.

My script `check_process.sh` contains the same lines plus an extra variable to pass the process' name :

```
#!/bin/bash
export ARG1=$1
export RES=$(pgrep -f ${ARG1})
if [[ $RES == "" ]]; then echo "-1" ; else echo "$RES"; fi
```

But this code does not work! 
If the process is currently running I get **two** `PID`s (the process' PID and *something  else*...), whereas when I check a process that is not running I get the *something else* !

I am puzzled. Any idea?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are probably matching the process and the process matching the process : )

Comment: `pgrep -f "$PROC_NAME" || echo "-1"`

Comment: Thanks for the more compact code. However when I use it in the script I still get the same problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the `-a` flag to `pgrep` inside your script, you can see something like that (I ran `./check_process.sh vlc`):

```
17295 /usr/bin/vlc --started-from-file ~/test.mkv
18252 /bin/bash ./check_process.sh vlc
```

So the "*something else*" is the `pid` of the running script itself.

The `pgrep` manual explains the `-f` flag:

> The pattern is normally only matched against the process name.  When -f is set, the **full command line** is used.

Obviously, the script command line contain the lookup process name (`'vlc'`) as an argument, hence it appears at the `pgrep -f` result.

If you're looking just for the process name matches you can remove the `-f` flag and get your desired result.

If you wish to stay with the `-f` flag, you can filter out the current `pid`:

```
#!/bin/bash
ARG1=$1
TMP=$(pgrep -f ${ARG1})
RES=$(echo "${TMP}" | grep -v $$)
if [[ $RES == "" ]]; then echo "-1" ; else echo "${RES}"; fi
```

Comment: If I remove the  `-f` the script is not working anymore. I haven't written in the question, but actually my process name is a path..   the process I am looking for is a script and "this path" is one of its parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your code! I was trying do the same with `ps`!

Comment: I corrected slightly your code:  on line 4 `${RES}` had to be `${TMP}`

Comment: I accepted you answer but I have an extra question. Ca you clarify what did you mean with "If you add the `-a` flag in your script" ?

Comment: Sure. I meant if you use `RES=$(pgrep -a -f ${ARG1})` in your original script

Comment: Which OS are you using? On my Linux box I get `pgrep: invalid option -- 'a'`

Comment: linux with `pgrep 3.3.12`

Comment: okay maybe it is something new. I have `pgrep -V : 
pgrep (procps version 3.2.7)`

Comment: Apparently. You can see the relevant manual [here](http://www.polarhome.com/service/man/?qf=pgrep&af=0&sf=0&of=Archlinux&tf=2)